# Java: returning a class User, the same as changing it?

Tags: java, class, return

I'm sorry if the question is stupid, I'm a beginner at programming Java...
I need to know if changing a class's value by using methods that go class by class until it gets there and changes the value (1), is the same as returning that class and changing the value on main (2)? Like if on (2) it creates some kind of pointer...

```
    public class User{
       //methods and constructor...
       String name = "";
       public String getName(){return name;}
       public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
    }

    public class UserList{
       //...
       User [] list = new User();
       //some User's inside list...
       public void setName(String name){
          list[0].setName(name);
       }
       public User getUser(){
          return list[0];
       }
    }

public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      UserList ul = new UserList();
      //is this (1):
      ul.setName("randomname");
      // the same as this (2):
      ul.getUser().setName("randomname");

   }
}
```

I don't understand if on (2) it actually returns the User or creates a "pointer" to User's memory. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. The two function calls point to the same list in memory.

Since one accesses `list[0]` and sets it the desired name, index 0 of `list` will be set to the desired name.

The other one gets the list, and then takes index 0 and sets it to the desired name. The overall effect is the same.

Remember, objects are references to a location in memory. Your array holds object references. When you return an index of this array object, you're returning the location *in memory* of the referenced object. As a result, that object is changed. However, when you call `list[0]`, you're accessing index 0, giving you *the same object* in memory. Thus, the net effect is the same.

Comment: Thanks! I've been thinking about this since I started learning Java. I started by learning C and intel Assembly before and Java seemed so abstract... but now I understand it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same!!
You are always referring to the same object list[0] either by setting his instance variable name directly or by returning the object and then modifying the instance variable.